# Firebase Realtime Database access value associated with a key

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have several problems. I was trying to verify a key using firebase-admin sdk via http.onReuest firebase functions.

So what I am doing here is, An admin can send an invite link to a user just by entering user's email-id on the web client. So when admin send an invitation, it pushed the email id into the firebase database and capture the auto generated key and attach the key into the URL and send the url to the user. When user click the link in the email, it makes the get request to the function below which splits the url and searches the id into the database and return the response accordingly.

But searching the value associated with the key isn't working. I have tried different code snippets but none working.

**A**  - /*Invite URL format -  https://web-url.com/invite/[**teacher-unique-id**]=[**auto-gen-key-id**] */

```
app.get('/invite/:token', (req, res) => {
    var result = req.params.token.split("=");
    const ref = database.ref('/teachers/' + result[0] + '/invited/');
    ref.once('value', (snap) => {
        snap.forEach((data) => {
            if (data.key === result[1]) res.send(data.val());
            else res.send("No user found... :(");
        });
    });
});


exports.fakeApp = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

**B**  -

```
// verify invite link and add to database
app.get('/invite/:token', (req, res) => {
    var result = req.params.token.split("=");
    const ref = database.ref('/teachers/' + result[0] + '/invited/');
    ref.orderByKey().equalTo(result[1]).on("child_added" /* also tried "value" */, (snap)=>{
        res.send({
            status:"sucess",
            value: snap.val()
        });
    });
});
```

Also, I keep hitting the end point every 15sec, sometime it show success but most of the time it shows Internal server error or timeout error or Error: could not handle the request

**EDIT**

```
    {
    "teachers":
    {
        "teacher-unique-id":
        {
            "invited":
            {
                "auto-gen-key-id": "student-email-id-1",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "student-email-id-2",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "student-email-id-3",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "student-email-id-4",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "student-email-id-5",
            },
            "accepted":
            {
                "auto-gen-key-id": "unique-student-id-1",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "unique-student-id-2",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "unique-student-id-3",
            }
        }
    },
    "students":
    {
        "unique-student-id-1":
        {
            "session-id-1":
            {
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
            },
            "session-id-2":
            {
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
            }
        },
        "unique-student-id-2":
        {
            "session-id-1":
            {
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
            },
            "session-id-2":
            {
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
                "auto-gen-key-id": "data",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a very inefficient interactive debugger. What precise line of this code isn't working? You'll likely also need to show us the JSON that you're trying to query here (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: The code is fine, no error so far but it is just not working as expected as it should. Sorry I can't share the JSON here since it is storing some sensitive data of the users and but I can share the structure here. Check the edit for the JSON Structure.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I fixed it bymyself! ---

// verify invite link and add to database

```
app.get('/invite/:token', (req, res) => {
    let result = req.params.token.split("=");
    let ref = database.ref('/teachers/' + result[0] + '/invited/');

    ref.child(result[1]).once('value').then(snap => {
        if (snap.val() != null) {
            res.send({
                msg: "Hurray! You exists",
                status: "Found",
                val: snap.val(), 
            });
        } else {
            res.send({
                msg: "Please Don't Hack me", 
                status: "Not Found"
            });
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message, error);
    });

});
```